Creating JSON data type via Entity Framework
I want to create table which has JSON column type via Entity Framework, for example:
CREATE TABLE Orders (order_id int, order_details JSON NOT NULL);

As you can see column order_details is JSON type. More about this feature in this article. Is it possible to do this from the code?

JSON isn't a data type in any of the released versions of SQL Server; that article clearly states it's in preview. Are you using an Azure SQL Database or Azure SQL Managed Instance (configured with the Always-up-to-date update policy)? JSON data in released versions is just a string and should be stored using a MAX length string.

@ThomA and siggermannen thank you guys very much, you are right, I will just use NVARCHAR(MAX)

Storing order details as JSON is NOT a good idea. You do need to filter and sort that data which means it should go into a separate table. In a properly designed database it's trivial to eg find out how many products of a certain category were ordered, their status and total values. Once you stuff them in a JSON column, you're forced to read the entire table to crack that table and read the data. Don't expect a JSON type and specialized indexes to fix that either. The XML type was built for the same thing and didn't fix it. They'll make querying a little faster but still too slow

@PanagiotisKanavos order_details was just example for this post, my real column and table have different purpose
